# MVC dropdown update the form not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know there are other posts for this, but I'm still not wrapping my head around it.

I would like write my MVC view to use a ViewModel that will allow text fields to change based on selections in a dropdownlist?

In the below example, I have a collection of Templates. I would like to see the dropdown list the Templates, then the user would select an item from the DropDownList, the code would populate the text fields, the user could edit those text fields, and finally submit the form with their changes.

What happens now is that every time the Submit code is called, it acts as if the dropdown was selected.

Model and ViewModel:

```
public class Template
{
    [Display(Name = "Template")]
    public int TemplateId {get; set;}
    public string TemplateName {get; set;}
    public string Subject {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}

public class TemplateViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Template")]
    public int LetterTemplateId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyWebProject.ViewModels.TemplateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("callforcontentproposaldetail","Project", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "frmProposalDetail"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Email Template</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LetterTemplateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LetterTemplateId,
                    new SelectList(Model.Templates as IEnumerable, "TemplateId", "TemplateName"),
                    new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "document.getElementById('frmProposalDetail').submit();", id = "ddlTemplate" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LetterTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="letterTemplateEditArea">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTemplate.TemplateSubject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedTemplate.Message, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SelectedTemplate.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width:100%;height:400px;font-size:11px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult callforcontentproposaldetail(Guid id)
{
    var proposal = db.CallForContentProposal.Find(id);

    var model = Mapper.Map<CallForContentProposalViewModel>(proposal);

    if (TempData["LetterTemplateId"] != null)
    {
        var emailTempId = 0;
        if (int.TryParse((string)TempData["LetterTemplateId"], out emailTempId))
        {
            var template = model.Templates.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TemplateId == emailTempId);
            model.SelectedTemplateId = emailTempId;
            model.Subject = template.Subject;
            model.Message = template.Body;
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult callforcontentproposaldetail(CallForContentProposalViewModel model, string SelectedTemplateId = "")
{
    // Do some saving of the current data
    // ...
    db.SaveChanges();

    // If this is the dropdownlist calling, redirect back to display the text fields populated
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedTemplateId))
    {
        TempData["LetterTemplateId"] = SelectedTemplateId;
        return RedirectToAction("callforcontentproposaldetail", new { id = model.CallForContentProposalId });
    }

    // On Submit, do other tasks

    return RedirectToAction("callforcontent", new {id =  model.CallForContentId});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it acts as if the dropdown was selected"?

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedTemplateId))` is still true, since the dropdown list is still selected. What I need is the dropdownlist and the submit button to both call back to the controller, but I need a way to know which is which. I need to differentiate between a dropdownlist callback and a submit button callback. Most of the examples I've found stop just short of this.

Comment: Well, where are you populating the `SelectedTemplateId` value before that `if` statement?  If there's nothing setting that value then it's going to be `null`.  Also, there's no such thing as a "dropdownlist callback".  If you need to fetch information from the server when the dropdownlist changes, I'd recommend creating a separate action for only that purpose and using AJAX to invoke that action and get the data client-side.

Comment: I haven't found a good example of doing the Ajax for what I want.

Comment: Based on the description it sounds like all you want from the AJAX call is to send it some kind of template identifier and receive back values to put in the form fields.  I would think any basic AJAX example would cover that.  The AJAX server-side action would just accept the identifier, and the AJAX call would include it (even just on the query string).  The action would return a "template object" as JSON.  If that's all you need then I highly recommend keeping it that simple, rather than what looks like an attempt to try to get MVC to behave like WebForms (it won't, thankfully).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to your comments, I worked out a way to use Ajax to do this for our situation (I tried to make it as generic as possible to reuse elsewhere):

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LetterTemplateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LetterTemplateId,
            Model.EmailTemplateSelect(),
        new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "EmailTemplateLoad.call(this,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'LetterTemplateSubject','LetterTemplateBody');", id = "ddlReviewRole" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LetterTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
EmailTemplateLoad = function(id, subjectTbName, messageTbName) {
    debugger;
    var ServiceUrl = "/Project/LoadTemplate?id=" + id;
    var content = '';
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ServiceUrl,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr, err) {
        },
        success: function (result, status) {
            $('#' + subjectTbName).val(result[0].Subject);
            $('#' + messageTbName).val(result[0].Message);
        }
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadTemplate(int id)
{
    var result = (from t in db.EmailBodyTemplate
        where t.EmailTemplateId == id
        select new
        {
            t.Subject,
            Message = t.Body
        });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I also followed this example, although it was incomplete:
[CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/599894/Howplustopluspopulateplusaplustextboxplusbasedplus%20CodeProject%20example)